# Iframe in Vtiger Module

Tags: iframe, vtiger, vtigercrm

I try to integrate an external URL on vtiger crm

To do that, I think on Ajax/iframe , does someone know which file to modify?
[image]

I want to add in Menu Iframe(sub Menu) if a click in Iframe a have in index.tpl
iframe to http://www.exemple.com

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my probleme , 
create a new module in .tpl i add
`<iframe>http://exemple.com</iframe>`